# Change url params string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, prototypejs, url-parameters

I want to remove some params from a URL string:

**For Example:**

I have a string like this:

```
var url = '/browse/102?color=red&type=car&rpp=10&ajax=1&change=1';
```

and an array like this:

```
var ignore = new Array("change","ajax");
```

**Result**:

```
/browse/102?color=red&type=car&rpp=10
```

What is the shortest and quickest way to achieve this?

Comment: there are many ways, but regular expressions will be your best choice. just write a function that does that using regular expressions. should be very few lines of code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a RegExp? Here is an example function:

```
var url = '/browse/102?color=red&type=car&rpp=10&a=mode&ajax=1&change=1&mode&test';
var ignore = new Array("change","ajax", "mode", "test"); 
alert(removeParams(url, ignore));

function removeParams(address, params)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
    {
       var reg = new RegExp("([\&\?]+)(" + params[i] + "(=[^&]+)?&?)", "g")
       address = address.replace(reg, function($0, $1) { return $1; });
    }
    return address.replace(/[&?]$/, "");
}​
```

Edit: Moved to a separate function like Michal B. did.

Comment: This is working good but I think there should be a small fix. If a param is repeated then it removes only one. For Example: `example.com/index?cat10&change=1&change=0` is converted to `example.com/index?cat10&change=0`

Answer (score 1):

Here jsfiddle example of a function that does that: http://jsfiddle.net/ANGsJ/1/
PS. I used the regex of Just_Mad, since mine was a bit uglier ;)

Comment: It fails on process('/browse/102?color=red&type=car&mode=2&rpp=10&ajax=1&change=1', ["mode"]);

Comment: What do you mean by it fails? Here you have an updated version. Just_Mad's regex removes too many characters (especially & and ?). Mine will not remove them at all, but it still should be a correct url: http://jsfiddle.net/ANGsJ/2/ . If you have problems you can always adjust the regex.

Comment: And here you have a quick solution if you really want to have pretty urls: http://jsfiddle.net/ANGsJ/4/

Comment: Well, we just have a bit different view of the correct result :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple utility I use in my application to play around with URL.
http://jsfiddle.net/gwB2C/

Simple to use:

```
var url_parser = new URLParser('/browse/102?color=red&type=car&rpp=10&ajax=1&change=1');
alert(url_parser.toString()); 
// result = "/browse/102?color=red&type=car&rpp=10&ajax=1&change=1"
url_parser.removeParams(["color", "type"]);
alert(url_parser.toString()); 
// result = "/browse/102?rpp=10&ajax=1&change=1"
url_parser.addParams({color:"green", test : 1});
alert(url_parser.toString()); 
// result = "/browse/102?rpp=10&ajax=1&change=1&color=green&test=1"
```